# How to have the exact same formatting of numbers in C++and R?

Tags: c++, r, formatting

I am writing a [functional test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_testing) in R for a program in C++. The typical output file has some columns as "string" and the other columns as "double". Then, I would like to use `diff` to compare the expected output file returned by R with the observed output file returned by C++.

In pseudo-C++, I simply do this:

```
stringstream ssTxt;
ssTxt.precision (7);
ssTxt.setf (ios::scientific);
for(i=0; i<10; ++i){
  ssTxt << names[i] << " " << values[0][i] << " " << values[1][i] << " " << values[2][i] << endl;
  // write in file and clear ssTxt
}
```

Here is a typical output:

```
item1 2.8200000e-01 500 4.1846912e-04
```

In R, I do that:

```
results <- data.frame(name="item1", val1=0.282, val2=500, val3=0.00041846912873)
write.table(x=format(results, digits=8, nsmall=7, scientific=TRUE), file=...)
```

Here is the output corresponding to the same data:

```
item1 2.82e-01 500 4.1846912e-04
```

As you can see, it almost works, but R doesn't add trailing 0 after "2.82". I prefer to change the R code rather than the C++ code. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried
`sprintf` or `formatC`?

To be specific I think

```
sprintf("%e", 2.82e-01)
```

should do the trick but as mentioned above have a look at help(sprintf), which describes the various formatting capabilities of this function ...

Comment: I hoped an option like "trailingzeros" would have worked, but indeed `sprintf` does the trick! As a result, I also need to use `gsub` to replace "NA" by "nan" (after `sprintf`, missing values are characters, i.e. "NA", not NA, and thus we can't use the "na" option of `write.table`).